# Location of Holo focused Button drawable

Tags: java, android, themes, drawable

Does anyone know what is the location of Holo theme focused button drawable? 
I would like to set it to my View on some event, but I can't find it.

Comment: You didn't find it in the in the `drawable` folders from the platforms versions starting with Honeycomb?

Comment: There is only android.R.drawable.btn_default

Comment: You can't access it that way, you'll need to copy it in your app and use it.

Comment: This is a good solution to my problem. However, setting button drawable changes the button size. How can I prevent that behavior?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1.first locate following location in your android sdk platforms folder   -

**yourandroidsdkrootfolderpath\platforms\android-11\data\res\drawable**
 (ex:D:\android\platforms\android-11\data\res\drawable)

2.find the xml file on folder named as **btn_default_holo_dark.xml**
    and it's contain like below code:

```
 <selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android">
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_window_focused="false" android:state_enabled="false"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_pressed="true" 
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_pressed_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_focused="true" android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_selected_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_enabled="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_holo_dark" />
    <item android:state_focused="true"
        android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable_focused_holo_dark" />
    <item
         android:drawable="@drawable/btn_default_normal_disable_holo_dark" />
</selector>
```

3.copy xml to your project **drawable** folder

4.copy drawable-hdpi,drawable-ldpi,drawable-mdpi images mentioned above xml like

**btn_default_normal,btn_default_normal_disable,btn_default_pressed,btn_default_selected,btn_default_normal,btn_default_normal_disable_focused,btn_default_normal_disable**

5.add style to your **style.xml** file like below

```
<style name="Custombutton" parent="Widget.Button">
        <item name="android:background">@android:drawable/btn_default_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="android:textAppearance">?android:attr/textAppearanceMedium</item>
        <item name="android:textColor">@android:color/primary_text_holo_dark</item>
        <item name="android:minHeight">48dip</item>
        <item name="android:minWidth">64dip</item>
    </style>
```

6.apply your button style like below code:

```
 <Button
    android:id="@+id/button1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    style="@style/Custombutton"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:text="Button" />
```

Comment: This changes the size of my button. I want it to keep it size. How can I do that? Could you edit your answer so I can accept it?

Answer (score 0):

Hdpi versions:

```
/<android sdk path>/platforms/android-15/data/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_default_disabled_holo.9.png
/<android sdk path>/platforms/android-15/data/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_default_focused_holo.9.png
/<android sdk path>/platforms/android-15/data/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_default_normal_holo.9.png
/<android sdk path>/platforms/android-15/data/res/drawable-hdpi/btn_default_pressed_holo.9.png
```

other resolutions are in `drawable-ldpi`,`drawable-mdpi`,`drawable-xhdpi` directories.

Comment: It changes the size of my button... How can I prevent that?