# Android: Button Drawable Default

Tags: android, button, drawable

I am trying to use the default Theme.holo button drawable for Android but I cannot find the standard one that's used whenever you create a button.  I have tried checking everywhere in the sdk\platforms\android-19\data\res\ but to no avail.  Any help searching for it would be appreciated.  Thanks in advance!

It looks like the one on the left here, but is mildy transparent.:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The drawables for your theme are located in:

```
platforms/android-*/data/res/drawable-*
```

Comment: As stated in the question, I have already searched here.  I cannot find what I am looking for in this folder.

Comment: Does that folder exist? What is in it?

Comment: the drawable folder contains a bunch of xmls, while the drawable-* contain .png's, none of which are the same as the button shown in the picture

Comment: Does this help: 
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440993/location-of-holo-focused-button-drawable

Comment: I have tried following the instructions on that post (that's how I got as far as I have), but the buttons located there are much darker or much lighter than the one currently displayed in my app

Comment: I think that you are looking for the holo dark theme button.

Answer (score 0):

See this [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17440993/location-of-holo-focused-button-drawable)

As it says you can find the drawables in

**yourandroidsdkrootfolderpath\platforms\android-11\data\res\drawable
(ex:D:\android\platforms\android-11\data\res\drawable)**

**EDIT**

Correct path

**yourandroidsdkrootfolderpath\platforms\android-8\data\res\drawable-mdpi**

Comment: Already have tried looking here, as described in my original post

Comment: I've found it..See yourandroidsdkrootfolderpath\platforms\android-8\data\res\drawable-mdpi @Mr_Skid_Marks